# Html2canvas, but text disappeared

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuejs3, jspdf, html2canvas

## Use html2canvas to convert html to canvas, but the text in the exported result disappears

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="exam">
            <h2>文本 Example</h2>
            <p>example example example example example example</p>
        </div>

        <br/><br/>
        <button @click="output">Print</button><br/><br/><br/>

        <p>Result:</p><br/>
        <div id="res"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'
const output = async () => {
    const dom = document.getElementById('exam')
    if (dom) {
        const cvs = await html2canvas(dom)
        document.getElementById('res')?.append(cvs)
    }
}
</script>
```

[image: export result]

html2canvas + vue3 + ts + sass.

Comment: Hi, code images are not allowed here, please edit it with actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder how often I see developers using `getElementById` or `querySelector` in vue components. You should make sure to use so called [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html).

You might try the following approach (which I didn’t test, but something like this should work).

```html
<div>
  <div ref="exam">
    <h2>文本 Example</h2>
    <p>example example example example example example</p>
  </div>
  <div ref="result"></div>
</div>
```

```
// inside script setup
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'

const exam = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
const result = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
const cvs = ref<??? | undefined>();

const output = async () => {
  if (!exam.value || !result.value) return;
  
  // saving the cvs value in a ref variable
  // to keep it available on rerenderings.
  cvs.value = await html2canvas(exam.value)
}

// add a watcher that append the result
// in order to apply it every time the
// something changes because vue will
// empty the element each time you update something.
watch(
  cvs,
  (newCvs) => {
    if (!newCvs || !result.value) return;
    // clean the result element
    result.value.innerHTML = '';

    // append the new created cvs
    result.value.append(newCvs);
  },
  { flush: 'post' },
)
```

Comment: thanks, but the output will be the same as before.

Comment: I created an example on stackblitz where the screenshot works with text: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rcnyes

Comment: Thanks. your have a nice code. and i found that fuking bug. if you add this code "img{ height: auto }", your well get the same bug.